# SQS FIFO random messages not beeing sent to lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have an service which integrates AWS SQS with AWS Lambda as trigger.

### What is happening

So basically when I send multiples messages to the SQS they are received(I confirmed it thru the AWS console) but some of them are not being sent to the lambda service(I confirmed it in our serverless app monitoring system). Not only they are not being sent from SQS to Lambda but they are being deleted for no reason.

### My code

The method that sends the message is:

```
import * as AWS from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";
import * as crypto from "crypto";

export class SqsService {
  private readonly sqsClient = new AWS.SQS({ region: "us-east-1" });

  public async sendMessages(
    queueUrl: string,
    messageGroupId: string,
    messages: any[]
  ) {
    const params = {
      QueueUrl: queueUrl,
      Entries: [],
    };
    const entries = [];
    let counter = 0;
    for (const message of messages) {
      const index = Math.floor(counter / 10);
      if (counter % 10 === 0) entries[index] = [];
      entries[index].push({
        Id: crypto
          .randomBytes(32)
          .toString("hex")
          .replace(/[\W_]+/g, ""),
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(message),
        MessageGroupId: messageGroupId,
      });
      counter += 1;
    }
    for (const entry of entries) {
      params.Entries = entry;
      await this.sqsClient.sendMessageBatch(params);
    }
  }
}
```

My serverless configuration for the function:

```
schedulerListener:
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-scheduler-listener
    handler: src/handlers/sqsScheduler.handler
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn: xxxxx
          batchSize: 10
```

### SQS Settings

[image]

## Edit

So actually my problem was that I had my SQS triggering both my prod and dev stage. Thanks everyone

Comment: Messages in an Amazon SQS are never "deleted without a reason". _Something_ would be receiving them and telling Amazon SQS to delete the message. When you say "some of them are not being sent to the lambda service", are you saying that some of them sit in the queue and appear not to be retrieved by Lambda? If so, can you tell us whether your messages have the same `MessageGroupId`, or is it different on each message? Are there any other apps consuming from the SQS queue? (For example, if you disconnected the Lambda function, do all messages remain in the queue?)

Comment: If your Lambda takes over 30 seconds to process messages, increase the visibility timeout and ensure it's not greater than the function timeout. Check for other consumers connected to the SQS queue and adjust the timeout if needed. 
Most important, set up a Dead Letter Queue (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html) to handle unprocessed messages.